# How to auto scale EC2 nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new in AWS, but I want to auto scale my application servers as following requirement:

- I may want to deploy 5 instances on Sunday night
- Then 10 instances on Tuesday
- 15 on Friday
- Then back down to 2 instances on Sat

I've create Auto Scaling Group, but I could not find where I can setup the above scaling configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Auto Scaling feature of Amazon EC2 can be used to launch or terminate Amazon EC2 instances to meet desired capacity.

In its simplest form, Auto Scaling **maintains a given number of instances** (eg 5 instances). If an instance fails, an the Availability Zone fails, then Auto Scaling will automatically launch replacement instances to maintain the given count.

The **Desired Capacity** can be modified via the execution of a **Scaling Policy** or a **Schedule**.

**Scaling Policies** tell Auto Scaling to modify the number of instances. For example, `+1` or `+100%`. These scaling policies are typically triggered by an **Amazon CloudWatch Alarm** based on metrics such as CPU Utilization or the number of jobs waiting in a queue.

However, your use case involves **Schedule Scaling** of instances. This is where you can specify a schedule for modifying:

- The **Desired Capacity** (the number of instances)
- The **Minimum** number of instances
- The **Maximum** number of instances (both used to set limits on the number of instances in the Auto Scaling group)

Your use-case would involve creating **four scheduled actions**.

See: [Scheduled Scaling documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/schedule_time.html)